# How can I export a fine printer friendly laravel view to PDF with laravel-snappy

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-snappy

I am using Larave-Snappy to converty laravel blade views to PDF.
It is working just fine but there are some elements such as the navigation bar that I don't want to be exported to PDF. 
I have created a print version of CSS which seem only to work for desktop printers but not when I am exporting to PDF. Is there a way I can avoid to export some laravel view blade to PDF with laravel-snappy with wkhtmtopdf. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `print-media-type` to true in your settings, this will use the print media css.

source: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/25